# Nested function for SLC-filling using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I wrote a function to fill in a bitmasked and filtered SLC from Landsat 7. I want multiple inputs because I need to fill in the SLC with different values each time like the median reflectance, the mean reflectance etc. There is a similar question at [GEE ImageCollection.map() with multiple-input function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302760) and I think I did the exact same thing but it doesn't work.

```
//Step 3 SLC-filling 

var ReplaceFunction = function(replacement) {
  
  var Replace = function(Im) {
    var replaced = ee.Im.unmask(replacement)
    return replaced; 
  }
  return Replace
}

var MedianReflectance = a2_lessthan50.median() //this is just calculating the median reflectance value
var ReplMedian = CollectionMapNoShadow.map(ReplaceFunction(MedianRefl)) //this is the collection that is masked and I want to fill in with the median values
```

The error I get is:

> cannot read property "unmask" of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my mistake was that I used ee.Im.unmask. Removing the ee. will make it work.

With ee you access server side functions and classes, but the moment you create an object by using that functionality it is already on server side.